# Can you open a pdf in a new browser tab without setting Content-Disposition from backend

Tags: javascript, html

The idea is we have a file generated from the backend and we want to display it in the browser in a new tab

We used to have an anchor tag like

```
<a href={documentUrl} target="_blank" </a>
```

Where the file was sent with "Content-Disposition:inline"  as part of the header

now Content-Disposition is gone because the backend wants the frontend to manage whether to open the file in a new tab or download it

is this possible? Preferably without using window.open or grabbing the blob data - using just the file url

**Edit:**  it's opening a new tab but then a pop up appears requesting where to download the file it doesn't actually present the file in the new tab

Comment: Is the anchor as you have it not working?

Comment: sorry good point - it's opening a tab but then a pop up appears requesting where to download the file it doesn't actually present the file in the new tab

Comment: You can try using an `object` tag to embed the PDF on a plain HTML page like in [How to display a PDF stream in a browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9840230/215552)