# Approach for Cross Platform Support PDF download using javascript / API

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, download, cross-platform

Is there any way to download the file that supports all the platforms web, mobile app etc?

We have a web application that developed on angular 8, we have multiple clients (80+) who are accessing our application using IFrame.

We have functionality that downloads the pdf file by API response type octet-stream, download is working fine on browsers, but not working on android/ios apps. because it requires native code but our application is a web app.

Can anyone please help us to the best approach that can download files on both browser / mobile apps? using angular / C# web API.

Note: Kindly don't delete this question by saying any code reference etc, I am looking for the approach.

Comment: Your android/ios apps dont have functions for download any files by direct link? how you access to your web app from android/ios apps

Comment: try <embed>  tag

Comment: Clients using our App on Iframe, we don't have access to the mobile app code

Answer (score 0):

[try like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840230/how-to-display-a-pdf-stream-in-a-browser-using-javascript)

```
<object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
       <embed src="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Comment: Sorry, Clients using our App on Iframe, we don't have access to the mobile app code

We are able to display the document but we don't have access to download the file.